# No me crea la carpeta al instalar mi template

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, npm, vite

Estoy intentando crear una plantilla instalable con Vue 3. Ya hice todos los pasos hasta el punto de [publicar mi plantilla](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saco-template-vue?activeTab=readme). Ya probé y (creo) que sí se instala todo correctamente, pero ahorita lo que quiero hacer, es que al utilizar el comando que me recomienda npm y adicionarle un nuevo nombre de la carpeta (`npm i saco-template-vue prueba-saco`) me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mis scripts son así:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "create": "node create.js",
    "postinstall": "mkdir $npx_input_1 && cp -r ./* $npx_input_1/"
},
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para corregirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu plantilla no esta publicada en NPM

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí. La eliminé. Ahora es https://www.npmjs.com/package/saco-vue?activeTab=explore

Ya he avanzado, pero aún hay errores.

Comment: `npm i saco-template-vue prueba-saco` -> este comando trata de instalar dos paquetes, `saco-template-vue` y `prueba-saco`

Comment: Pues mi intención es que instale `saco-vue` y cree una carpeta con el nombre `prueba-saco`, no que instale 2 cosas.

Comment: `npm i` / `npm install` no crea ningun directorio por ti (excepto `node_modules` si no existe). El objectivo del comando es instalar paquetes en el directorio desde donde lo corres (crea el directorio `node_modules`, y agrega el paquete como dependencia en `package.json`, creandolo de ser necesario). Quiza estas confudiendo el commando con `npm init`

Comment: ¿Pero entonces cómo hace vite, por ejemplo `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue` y crea la carpeta llamada "my-vue-app"? Es eso lo que pretendo hacer.

Comment: No uses entonces `npm install`. `npm create` y `npm init` son el mismo comando (`create` es un alias de `init`), `npm install` es distinto y sirve para lo que te explique.

Comment: En un princio tenía "create" en los "scripts", pero no me funcionaba nada.

Comment: Subí cambios. Mi script ahora es `"create": "node create.mjs"`, pero ahora me arroja el error npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-saco-vue - Not found 

¿Por qué? Jajaja

Comment: porque `create-saco-vue` no existe en el NPM registry

Comment: Yo sé que no existe. Lo que quiero es crear mi proyecto, no hace uno llamado `create-saco-vue`

Comment: O sea, al unas npm create `saco-vue` me instale todas mis carpetas y archivos y haga todo lo demás, no busco más.